# Identify "Large Number of Pages Pointing to the Same Canonical URL" source in Bing Webmaster Tools

Tags: canonical-url, bing-webmaster-tools

I'm getting a "Large Number of Pages Pointing to the Same Canonical URL" for one of the websites in my Bing Webmaster Tools. The alert goes on to explain:

> Canonical tags can be used to help de-dupe URLs for pages with the same or very similar content. Bing has detected that your site is using what appears to be the same canonical URL for a large number of pages that are not the same. This may be indicative of a problem with your HTML template, content publishing system, or site code. You should review the source of your pages and check if the URLs used inside the " /> are not accidentally pointing to the same location for all (or too many) pages.

Bing have a [help page](http://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/alert-large-number-of-pages-pointing-to-the-same-canonical-url-d66b104e) about this, but this only explains what the alert means, not the source. Is it possible within Bing Webmaster Tools to identify the specific URLs which Bings is using to trigger this alert?

Answer (score 1):

You think it would be helpful if Bing would at least give a few samples of the suspect pages. But Google does the same sorts of things so don't think it too bad of Bing.

It is incumbent upon a site owner to check their links on their sites but that may be too large a task these days with sites growing ever larger and more sophisticated.

Here is a tool that should help: http://www.screamingfrog.co.uk/seo-spider/ This tool is designed for exactly the purpose you need right now including canonical links.

It is free to a point, then requires a license. If your site is less than the subscribed number of pages for the free version, there is no cost. Either way, it is not too expensive.

Clearly something went wrong. It can be rather easy to make a mistake of this magnitude. I once did a fat-finger typo on a base URL in one of my templates creating bad links to over 500,000 pages. I discovered this well after the fact and it took a while to clean-up. It happens.

Comment: I already use the paid version and know there are external tools for this. I just wanted to know if there was anywhere within Bing to find it. Nice alternative thinking though!

Comment: @AndrewLott Bing has not loved me too much historically, so I do not love Bing back. ;-) I do not know Bing at all as a result. They do have their version of a webmaster tools that may be useful. Bing has been liking me more lately so my heart is softening... I feel like the Grinch.